# Switch Divs between iPhone and iPad

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css, ipad

I am trying to switch between different divs (on the same html page) depends on if the device is iPhone or iPad, I tried all possible ways I can think of and it doesn't work. I want to have nav_ipad displayed and nav_iphone disappeared when it's opened on ipad, but I nav_iphone always show regardless what I did. Here's my code, please help me if you can, thank you!

**html code**

```
<nav id="nav_ipad"> 
<ul>
<li><a href="about.html"><b>A</b>BOUT</a></li>
<li><a href=""><b>P</b>ROCESS</a></li>
<li><a href=""><b>W</b>ORK</a></li>
<li><a href=""><b>C</b>ONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<nav id="nav_iphone">
<ul>
<li><a href="site/about.html"><b>A</b>BOUT</a></li>
<li><a href=""><b>W</b>ORK</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**Javascript**

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {

$('#nav_ipad').hide();
}


if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {

$('#nav_iphone').hide();
// document.getElementById("nav_iphone").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Having form fitting css would be far more elegant and device/screen-size independant.

Comment: Just as @TheZ has stated, you may want to look into media queries in CSS to help you tailor this effect which will be more "universal" for other devices as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use css only, the top link tag is for iPhone and the other for iPad

```
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" rel="stylesheet" href="css/small-device.css" type="text/css" title="no title"/>

<link media="only screen and (device-width: 768px)" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ipad.css" type="text/css" title="no title"/>
```

Then create 2 css files and style away :)